# ReactJS how to change react-switch text from V, X

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this Switch component I'm using from react-switch.

```
import Switch from 'react-switch';


render() {
    return <Switch
             onChange={this.onChangeStatus}
             onClick={this.onChangeStatus}
             checked={this.state.storeStatus}
             offColor="#e8e8e8"
             onColor="#62a5f7"
             id="storeStatus"/>
}
```

Now I looked every where and i can't find a way to change it's default 'X', 'V'
texts to a 'yes' 'no'.

I found this question in stack overflow that refers to react-native-switch

[How to show text (YES/NO) inside a switch in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865391/how-to-show-text-yes-no-inside-a-switch-in-react-native)

But it does not work for me.

And I could not find any value I can pass in order to change the default text of the switch, in the documentation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-switch

https://github.com/markusenglund/react-switch

I'm probably missing something because it is way to basic to not be implemented.
Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find your answer on the demo page

https://react-switch.netlify.com

Go down to **Custom icons** section.